# PHP PDO bindValue using MySQL IN()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This query of mine returns nothing. It doesn't throw any errors. Can't find solution on this site. What is wrong here?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE `tags` IN (:tags)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':tags', 'one, two, three');
$stmt->execute();
// 0 results, should be more
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try to Use PDO::[bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) instead.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE `tags` IN (:tags)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':tags', implode(",", array('one, two, three')));
$stmt->execute();
```

Although using implode kinda defeats the original purpose of bind, and the stringified array is binded instead of the original array.

Comment: Throws error `Cannot pass parameter x by reference`

Comment: one of the parameters I pass is `four'); DROP TABLE votes;--`

Comment: Of course, do not include the user-input directly in the query

Comment: This answer should be deleted.

Comment: why is this an answer????
has someone had success with this???????

Answer (score 3):

That's not going to do what you want, regardless of whether you use bindParam() or bindValue().

A SQL query parameter takes the place of *one value* only.  You can't bind a string containing commas and have it be interpreted as several values.  You need one parameter placeholder for each distinct value in your list.

Also, you don't need to bind parameter value at all with PDO.  You can pass an array to execute().  In this case, I'd use positional parameters instead of named parameters.  PDO supports both, but don't mix them in one query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE `tags` IN (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$params = explode(', ', 'one, two, three');
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: ` You can't bind a string containing commas and have it be interpreted as several values`
So @Bill, this is not true, the query STRING will accept the seperated values, since a query as the name says it is a stirng, it is not familiar with "values","params" or whatever, an IN value, is a concatted string of possible values, but again a string

Comment: @TobiasHagenbeek, I think you're confusing parameter binding with string interpolation. We're talking about the former, not the latter.

Comment: i guess you make a good point then :)

Answer (score 0):

Your bind value has an error.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':tags', 'one, two, three');
```

should be

```
$stmt->bindValue(':tags', "'one', 'two', 'three'");
```

Comment: This is not valid